# mono optimizer flags (--shared emit per-domain code) (--intrins)

Tags: optimization, mono, compilation, flags, compiler-flags

can someone explain what these two optimization flags do?

`--intrins = Intrinsic method implementations`

`--shared = Emit per-domain code`

best Regards
Goblin

Answer (score 2):

Intrinsic method implementations means that some specific methods in the class libraries are implemented with special instructions sequeneces by the JIT directly, instead of following the normal IL or internal C code. This option should be always enabled, since it allows the JIT to generate much faster code.

The shared option means that the code generated by the JIT should be domain neutral, that is it will be valid for any application domain (normally the JIT will specialize the code for each domain). This option should be used when the application uses many applications domains that execute mostly the same code and you want to minimize memory usage and reduce JIT time. The drawback is that shared code is slightly slower in some cases than domain-specilized code.